# What's wrong with my javascript iife for loading script dynamically

Tags: javascript

There's no message error https://jsfiddle.net/f197cjty/ so I can't see why it doesn't play youtube

```
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>

    <script>
    // 1. ytplayer code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#IFrame_Player_API

    (
        function(){
            
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";

            var before = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            before.parentNode.insertBefore(s, before);

        }
    )();


    var player;


    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() 
    {
            player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', 
            {
              height: '390',
              width: '640',
              playerVars: 
              {
                listType:'playlist',
                list: 'RDEMe12_MlgO8mGFdeeftZ2nOQ'
              }
            });
    }



     </script>
```

Comment: Just a typo for https protocol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to run an `http` script in an `https` environment. Change the url for YouTube to `https://www.youtube.com/player_api`.